# How to get the player to play in more browsers

Tags: video.js

I the video.js player set up, but the Player doesn't appear in IE8, it does appear and play in IE10 (proably IE9 too). 
It appears and plays in Chrome and IOS, but only appears in Firefox (doesn't play)..

```
<script>
  _V_.options.flash.swf = "http://theurl.com/video-js/video.js.swf"
</script>
<script>
videojs.options.flash.swf = "http://url.com/video-js/video.js.swf"
</script>

<video id=".mp4" class="video-js vjs-default-skin"
  controls preload="none" width="640" height="264"
  poster="[var.base_url]/[var.thumb_file]"
  data-setup='{"example_option":true}'>
  <source src="http://url.com/uploads/YfGNOH0ek3aSkGJll3Ml_1200k.mp4" 
type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

Can you provide some help so it appears and plays in most browsers? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does this example work in all those browsers for you?
http://jsbin.com/okofet/1/edit
(it does for me)

Try replacing all your `<script>` tags with:

```
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.0/video.js"></script>
```

(You might also want a different id than '.mp4'. I'm not sure if that's valid)

Comment: Thanks for that reply. In your link I see the player, but it plays nothing. I replaced all the script tags, as instructed, but there's no change. If .mp4 may not be valid, what would be valid, please?

Comment: I get the same behavior as Ben.  Is mp4 not valid for flash fallback?