# Can you explain about valid video id's?

Tags: html, video.js

In this posting

[How to get the player to play in more browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918558/how-to-get-the-player-to-play-in-more-browsers)

the reply was:

"You might also want a different id than '.mp4'. I'm not sure if that's valid".

Can someone help me pick a valid id? And for my own education could you explain why .mp4  may not be valid video id?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

See [what are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html).

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").